# How can I realize a missed call?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I understand that the call log is off limits for developers for Windows Phone 8.1.
However, what if I only want to know if a call was missed without any further details?

I'm really looking for a "if (MissedCalls == true)" type of support.

Any suggestions?

Here's the [app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacVrH9xpYc) that I'm looking to implement this feature with.

Comment: [did you check this ?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416383.aspx) there is a `IOM` properties who returns whether the call was missed or something.

Comment: @Touk your link is for windows mobile not windows phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no API for that

It will be added in future .[Windows Feedback](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1905841-please-allow-readonly-access-to-call-history-and)